# Displaying datatable from database

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to display data from the database into a datatable and I am getting no results. I tested the queries with JDBC with exact select statement to see if it returns any row, and it always worked. But when I try to have the data from the database into my datatable I get no results. I even made a fake dummy data just to populate my datatable. I must be doing something wrong in the index.xhtml file that I don't know of. What could I doing wrong ? any help would be appreciated ?

edit: first I went to with Primefaces with their datatable example, and than I went with simple jsf style datatable like I have here and neither of those worked when I try to do it with the database

UserDAO.java

```
public class UserDAO {

    private static final String USERNAME = "something";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "something";
    private static final String CONN_STRING =
            "jdbc:sqlserver://petunia.arvixe.com.....something";

    public List<Report> getUserList() {
        List<Report> list = new ArrayList<Report>();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            String sql = "SELECT id, tag,asset_name, model, ser_no, value, \n" +
"                                asset_condition, asset_type FROM  assets";
            String sql1 = "SELECT name, address, city,state,zip, phone, district FROM location";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
              ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            result = ps.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                Report rep = new Report();
                rep.setId(result.getInt("id"));
                rep.setTag(result.getString("tag"));
                rep.setName(result.getString("asset_name"));
                rep.setModel(result.getString("model"));
                rep.setSerial(result.getString("ser_no"));
                rep.setValue(result.getFloat("value"));
                rep.setCondition(result.getString("asset_condition"));
                rep.setType(result.getString("asset_type"));
                rep.setLocationName(result.getString("name"));
                rep.setAddress(result.getString("address"));
                rep.setCity(result.getString("city"));
               rep.setState(result.getString("state"));
                rep.setZip(result.getString("zip"));
                rep.setPhone(result.getString("phone"));
                rep.setDistrict(result.getInt("district"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
                ps.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are making a report:

```
Report rep = new Report();
```

...but not adding it to your list. Add this:

```
 Report rep = new Report();
 list.add(rep);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your problem is this code:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
result = ps.executeQuery();
```

You are overwriting your `sql` statement immediately with the statement `sql1`.

I think, you probably want to select the `assets` with **THEIR** `location`s. In SQL you can use a `JOIN` to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this syntax

```
String sql = "SELECT id, tag,asset_name, model, ser_no, value, \n" +
             " asset_condition, asset_type FROM  assets";
String sql1 = "SELECT name, address, city,state,zip, phone, district FROM location";

ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);

result = ps.executeQuery();
```

You will get as a result only the execution of the second query. I think that in your case you are trying to get a result from both tables assets and location so you should use a join between the 2 tables.